# Apache Derby Insert Trigger - Retrieving inserted record

Tags: sql, triggers, derby, sql-insert

I have a insert trigger for my Derby Database. The point of this trigger is to take everything that is inserted into table_1 and copy that information into table_2. My code works and adds a row to table_2 when I input static numbers, but I cannot figure a way to simply get the value of the row that was just inserted into table_1.

```
create trigger insert_new_row
after insert on table_1
referencing new as insertedrow
for each row
insert (a,b,c)
values(a,b,c);
```

In the `values` part I need the values that were just inserted into table_1 (newsest values). I have also tried- `(insertedrow.a`) (`:insertedrow.a`) (`new.a`) (select a from table_1) and (select a from table_1 where a = insertedrow.a) but none of those work.

Example- if the insert statement reads-

```
insert into table_1 (a,b,c)
values(1,2,3);
```

I need to the trigger to insert a row into table_2 with the same values (1,2,3). The collumn names are the same so a trigger of

```
create trigger insert_new_row
after insert on table_1
referencing new as insertedrow
for each row 
insert (a,b,c)
values(1,2,3);
```

will work but is not practical since I need this to hapen behind the scene and need the values to change with the origional insert statement. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing an `into` clause for the insert.

The following works for me:

```
create trigger insert_new_row
  after insert on table_1
  referencing new as insertedrow
  for each row 

insert into table_2 (a,b,c)
values( insertedrow.a, insertedrow.b, insertedrow.c);
```